# GridDB on Ubuntu with NodeJS - Error: 'gridstore.h' file not found

Tags: node.js, database, ubuntu, griddb

I am working on a project that involves using GridDB with Node.js on Ubuntu. I have followed the installation instructions and made sure all the necessary dependencies are installed. However, when I try to compile my Node.js application that includes the GridDB library, I encounter the following error:

```
fatal error: gridstore.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I have checked the installation directory and confirmed that the 'gridstore.h' header file exists. I also verified that the required GridDB libraries were properly linked during the compilation process. Despite this, I am still facing the same error.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue while working with GridDB on Ubuntu and Node.js? How can I resolve this 'gridstore.h' file not found error and successfully compile my application? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!